# Unexpected validation errors in Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jsp

I have a strange error to my code. I am writing code for a eshop.

I have written code for validation when admin add products where the name field is empty. When I click the submit button the addProduct page reload with the message error that I defined.

With similar way I write code for validation when admin edit a product. I try to edit a product with an empty name that violates the NotEmpty that I have defined at the Product.java.

**AddProduct at HomeController**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/productInventory/addProduct", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addProductPost(@Valid @ModelAttribute("product") Product product, BindingResult result,
        HttpServletRequest request) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "addProduct";
    }
```

**addProduct.jsp**

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <form:errors path="productName" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;" />
            <form:input path="productName" id="name" class="form-Control" />
        </div>
```

**EditProduct at HomeController**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/productInventory/editProduct", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editProduct(@Valid @ModelAttribute("product") Product product, Model model, BindingResult result,
        HttpServletRequest request) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "editProduct";
    }
```

**editProduct.jsp**

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <form:errors path="productName" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;" /> 
            <form:input path="productName" id="name" class="form-Control"
                value="${product.productName}" />
        </div>
```

**product.java**

```
@Column(name="productName")
@NotEmpty (message = "The product name must not be null.")
private String productName;
```

When I try to click the submit button on editProduct (with an empty name) I take:

```
HTTP Status 400 - 
type Status report
message 
description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M17
```

What's going wrong?

**EDIT**

editProduct.jsp

```
    <%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/header.jsp"%>


<div class="container-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>Edit Product</h1>

            <p class="lead">Please update the product information here:</p>
        </div>

        <form:form
            action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/productInventory/editProduct"
            method="post" commandName="product" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <form:hidden path="productId" value="${product.productId}" />

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <form:errors path="productName" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;" />
                <form:input path="productName" id="name" class="form-Control"
                    value="${product.productName}" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="category">Category</label> <label
                    class="checkbox-inline"><form:radiobutton
                        path="productCategory" id="category" value="instrument" />Instrument</label>
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><form:radiobutton
                        path="productCategory" id="category" value="record" />Record</label> <label
                    class="checkbox-inline"><form:radiobutton
                        path="productCategory" id="category" value="accessory" />Accessory</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="description">Description</label>
                <form:textarea path="productDescription" id="description"
                    class="form-Control" value="${product.productDescription}" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="price">Price</label>
                <%-- <form:errors path="productPrice" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;" /> --%>
                <form:input path="productPrice" id="price" class="form-Control"
                    value="${product.productPrice}" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="condition">Condition</label> <label
                    class="checkbox-inline"><form:radiobutton
                        path="productCondition" id="condition" value="new" />New</label> <label
                    class="checkbox-inline"><form:radiobutton
                        path="productCondition" id="condition" value="used" />Used</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="status">Status</label> <label class="checkbox-inline"><form:radiobutton
                        path="productStatus" id="status" value="active" />Active</label> <label
                    class="checkbox-inline"><form:radiobutton
                        path="productStatus" id="status" value="inactive" />Inactive</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="unitInStock">Unit In Stock</label>
                <%-- <form:errors path="unitInStock" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;" /> --%>
                <form:input path="unitInStock" id="unitInStock" class="form-Control"
                    value="${product.unitInStock}" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="manufacturer">Manufacturer</label>
                <form:input path="productManufacture" id="manufacturer"
                    class="form-Control" value="${product.productManufacture}" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="productImage">Upload
                    Picture</label>
                <form:input id="productImage" path="productImage" type="file"
                    class="form:input-large" />
            </div>

            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-default">
            <a href="<c:url value="/admin/productInventory" />"
                class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
        </form:form>

    </div>
</div>
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/footer.jsp"%>
```

**header.jsp**

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

<title>My Music Store</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" />"
    rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Carousel core CSS -->
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/carousel.css" />"
    rel="stylesheet">

<!-- My Main CSS style-->
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/main.css" />" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<!-- NAVBAR
================================================== -->
<body>
    <div class="navbar-wrapper">
        <div class="container">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                        data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"
                        aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                            class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                            class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Music Store</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="<c:url value="/" />">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="<c:url value="/productList" />">Products</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                        <li><a href="<c:url value="/admin/" />">Admin</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
            </nav>

        </div>
    </div>
```

**EDIT AGAIN**

**Product**

```
    package com.entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="productId")
    private String productId;

    @Column(name="productName")
    @NotEmpty (message = "The product name must not be null.")
    private String productName;

    @Column(name="productCategory")
    private String productCategory;

    @Column(name="productDescription")
    private String productDescription;

    @Min (value = 0, message = "The product price must no be less than zero.")
    @Column(name="productPrice")
    private double productPrice;

    @Column(name="productCondition")
    private String productCondition;

    @Column(name="productStatus")
    private String productStatus;

    @Min (value = 0, message = "The product unit must no be less than zero.")
    @Column(name="unitInStock")
    private int unitInStock;

    @Column(name="productManufacture")
    private String productManufacture;

    @Transient /*do not store to database*/
    private MultipartFile productImage;

    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(String productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public String getProductCategory() {
        return productCategory;
    }

    public void setProductCategory(String productCategory) {
        this.productCategory = productCategory;
    }

    public String getProductDescription() {
        return productDescription;
    }

    public void setProductDescription(String productDescription) {
        this.productDescription = productDescription;
    }

    public double getProductPrice() {
        return productPrice;
    }

    public void setProductPrice(double productPrice) {
        this.productPrice = productPrice;
    }

    public String getProductCondition() {
        return productCondition;
    }

    public void setProductCondition(String productCondition) {
        this.productCondition = productCondition;
    }

    public String getProductStatus() {
        return productStatus;
    }

    public void setProductStatus(String productStatus) {
        this.productStatus = productStatus;
    }

    public int getUnitInStock() {
        return unitInStock;
    }

    public void setUnitInStock(int unitInStock) {
        this.unitInStock = unitInStock;
    }

    public String getProductManufacture() {
        return productManufacture;
    }

    public void setProductManufacture(String productManufacture) {
        this.productManufacture = productManufacture;
    }

    public MultipartFile getProductImage() {
        return productImage;
    }

    public void setProductImage(MultipartFile productImage) {
        this.productImage = productImage;
    }



}
```

Comment: Show your html form on editProduct.jsp, please?

Comment: I just updated my post. It is unexpected that when I update an existing product (without violate restrictions) all are fine.. The problem occurs when one of the restrictions violate...

Comment: Looks like spring unable to convert some form value to the field of `Product`. Could you show full code of class `Product`?

Comment: @KenBekov I updated my first post..

Comment: Is your addproduct form working fine and it is a multipartform too? So, I guess you have defined the CommonsMultipartResolver bean, do not you? You need to declare the MultipartFile field out of the bean, as a @RequestParam on the requestmapping method.

Comment: Now I am working on it and I see that neither addProduct works fine but I do not get a HTTP Status 400... So, I have changed something somewhere and I am trying to find it. Yes, I have defined 
org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver

Comment: Hi again. I realize that the editProduct does not work fine without use of form errors. So probably the error(s) are somewhere in the previous code.

Comment: I cannot find where is the error for editProduct. Can you help me for this error with the code I have posted. Let me know if you want some more code. Thank you

Comment: What is your current code? What error are you getting now?